# asp.net c# conditional within data repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net, image, conditional-statements

I want to do something very simple, only display an asp:image when I have value (i.e. not NULL) for the current DataItem.

As below, Image1 should only be output when there is a value for Image1 (i.e. Eval("Image1")) which is a field in the current DataItem.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="NewsPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="NewsRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="newsItem">
                <h3><%# Eval("Title") %></h3>
                <div class="images">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# UrlHelper.NewsImageUrl((int)Eval("Id"),1) %>' />
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# UrlHelper.NewsImageUrl((int)Eval("Id"),2) %>' />
                </div>
                <div class="content"><%# Eval("Content") %></div>
            </div>
            <br class="clear" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Is there some simple conditional statements I can use in the ASPX page? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to check if it is null from codebehind

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" visible='<%# HasData(Eval("image")) %>' ImageUrl='<%# UrlHelper.NewsImageUrl((int)Eval("Id"),1) %>'
```

C#

```
public bool HasData(object img)
{
  if(img!=null) {return true;}
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. I wish I had posted before I hit my laptop screen...doh!

Answer (score 1):

@ aspx page.

```
<div class="images">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# UrlHelper.NewsImageUrl((int)Eval("Id"),1) %>' Visible = '<%#(Container.DataItem != null) ? true: false) %>' />
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# UrlHelper.NewsImageUrl((int)Eval("Id"),2) %>' Visible = '<%#(Container.DataItem != null)  ? true: false) %>' />
</div>
```

Comment: var.ToString() might fail and throw exception if value is null